# Web app integrated in a CMS

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, wordpress

I want to build a site that allows user to get filtered subsets of some information I have stored on a database. The information will change frequently and I will want to create a post every now and again to say when new information or features become available, so the site has CMS aspects and web app aspects.

Coming from a desktop programming environment, I have to admit I'm not entirely certain how far a CMS like Drupal or WordPress can take me. The web app would basically be a form with several interdependent options and a Submit button. When the Submit button is clicked, I would want to call a web service that returns the information in one of a variety of formats.

So will I need to install my CMS and have an iframe or just a link to the web app which is developed completely outside of it, or can I build my web app's front end directly in the CMS (and hopefully achieve a nice, integrated look) and just have it call the service behind a button?

I half-expect that this web app would become a WordPress/Drupal plugin, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: please.. clarify this question, it hurts my brain.

Comment: Lol! I tried, but I'll give it another go. If I develop a desktop app in Delphi or WinForms, I can create a form and place a button on it to call my web service. I'm asking if I can similarly develop the UI for my web app in the CMS (given that the UI is quite simple) or if the web app must be developed separately and somehow embedded in the CMS pages (iframe or something like it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Try out jquery, I think is already included (at leas in wordpress). "Break into" the layot part add js file of your own that makes an AJAX call to a url and returns some HTML from there and puts that content into a certain HTML component (a div that you also add there by your self with a certain id). 
User clicks a button, triggers the ajax call and voila.

There are also complicated ways like developing your own plugin that makes SOAPCalls and integrated with the wordpress/drupal etc. But as you say that you are a desktop developer this is the closest aproach to you knwoledge and perspective.

[AJAX LOAD WITH JQUERY](http://api.jquery.com/load/)